# Is that possible to filter the next activity based on the user group and show in the drop down box?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have a scenario as given in the below workflow diagram using core service.

[image]

1. First step is manual step author will create/edit content and finish the activity and it is assigned to everyone.
2. In the second step, I want to do filter the users based on their groups.
3. In the third step, couple of scenario

   a. If the user belongs to group "A" I want to list out all the next 3 available activities, User A can choose any one of these 3 activities.

   b. If the user belongs to group "B", I want to list out "Reviewer" and "Approver" activity as next activity, user b can select any one of these 2.

Can any one give some idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should turn your problem around. Yes, it is possible, but the amount of knowledge required will be a huge barrier for you to implement.

So, instead think about it differently.

- Change your "Filter Next activity" automated activity to an automatic decision, and have your code that determines the group membership also determine which activity should be next
- have 2 forward paths from there - 1 for the users of Group A, other for the users of group B
- on each forward path, have different selection options. You *may* try having links to the same activity from 2 different manual decisions, I don't know if that works though.

Worst case scenario you'll have repeated activities (not in name, but in function), and you saved yourself about 2 months of headaches trying to cope with the learning curve of doing CME extensions.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer to your initial question is: "no, this functionality is not out of the box".

But of course many things are possible by implementing critical parts yourself.

1. You'd probably need a GUI extension of some sorts to allow the user to pick from a list.
2. You'd need to store the information between phases of your custom solution.
3. And you'd then need some code in an automated workflow activity to implement the picking of the next activity.

Most of these steps have been covered in other questions already. Did you have a look for each of these? If so, you might want to share how far you already got and where you are stuck.